# Why that Spring Framework Documentation's table of contents is gone?

Tags: spring, document

I remember there was a table of contents in the document before but now is gone.
That makes it inconvenient to find the specified chapter.
And I see the other's project still has the table of contents.
Is it something wrong with this doc page?

Spring Framework Documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html

And others project like Spring Boot :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features

Comment: you can raise this concern by creating an issue ticket in GitHub and if it is valid surely it will be added to the project pipeline

Answer (score 3):

I have the same symptoms, but with Spring Framework project, not Spring Boot. I managed to download PDF versions of the topics. They're at:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/pdf/core.pdf
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/pdf/testing.pdf
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/pdf/data-access.pdf
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/pdf/web.pdf
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/pdf/web-reactive.pdf
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/pdf/integration.pdf
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/pdf/languages.pdf
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/reference/pdf/appendix.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Both links lead to [Spring features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html)

[image]